# Comparar dos coches (Arrays) introduciendo sus identificadores por scanner

Tags: java, array

¿Cómo podría sacar el coche con mayor número de kilómetros pidiendole al usuario que introduzca dos identificadores de los coches?.

```
public class Coches {

    int identificador;
    int kilometros;

    public Coches(){}

    public Coches(int identificador, int kilometros) {
        this.identificador = identificador;
        this.kilometros = kilometros;
    }

    public int getIdentificador(){
        return identificador;
    }

    public int getKilometros(){
        return kilometros;
    }
}

public class Pruebas{

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

         Coches coche = new Coches();

         // Se almacenan un numero máximo de coches (4).

         Coches array [] = new Coches [4];

         int contador = 0;

         while (contador < array.length) {

             System.out.println("Introduce el identificador del coche : ");

             int identificador;
             int kilometros;

             System.out.print("Identificador :");
             identificador = teclado.nextInt();

             System.out.print("Kilometros :");
             kilometros = teclado.nextInt();

             coche = new Coches(identificador,kilometros);

             array [contador] = coche;
             contador++;

             System.out.print("Coche dado de alta");
             System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.print("Se ha alcanzado el maximo de coches.\n");

        //Busca cual realizo mayor kilometraje:
        int maxKilometros = 0;
        int indiceCoche = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){                  
            if(array[i].getKilometros() > maxKilometros){
                maxKilometros = array[i].getKilometros();
                indiceCoche = i;
            }                   
        }

        System.out.print("El coche que ha recorrido más kilometros es:"  + array[indiceCoche].getIdentificador() + " Kilometros: "+ array[indiceCoche].getKilometros() +"\n");
    }
}
```

Necesito que en la última parte se introduzcan dos identificadores por teclado, y una vez introducidos los compare y me digan cual es el coche de mayor autonomía.

```
// Comparar dos coches introduciendo sus identificadores.

System.out.print("Introduzca el primer identificador :");
System.out.print("Introduzca el segundo identificador :");
```

¿Cómo se podría hacer?.

Gracias, Saludos.

Gracias a Jorgesys por la respuesta en el anterior hilo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo debes leer el identificador por teclado

```
int idcoche1 = teclado.nextInt(),
    idcoche2 = teclado.nextInt(),
    indiceCoche1 = -1,
    indiceCoche2 = -1;
```

luego usas el mismo ciclo que ya tienes:

```
for(int i = 0; i< array.length; i++){                  
    if(array[i].getIdentificador() == idcoche1){
        indiceCoche1 = i;
    }
    if(array[i].getIdentificador() == idcoche2){
        indiceCoche2 = i;
    }               
}
```

luego comparas los coches:

```
if (array[indiceCoche1].getKilometros() > array[indiceCoche2].getKilometros(indiceCoche2)){
    System.out.print("El coche 1 tiene mas autonomia");
} else {
    System.out.print("El coche 2 tiene mas autonomia");
}
```

Recuerda hacer las validaciones correspondientes en la entrada del usuario (este es un ejemplo):

```
int coche = -1;
do {
    try {
        coche = teclado.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.print("HAs ingresado algo mal");
    }
} while (coche > 1);
```

puedes ver mas sobre validación en este link: [EL LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496239/how-do-i-keep-a-scanner-from-throwing-exceptions-when-the-wrong-type-is-entered)

*Disclaimer: Siento si hay algún error, pero no tengo ningún IDE a la mano, por lo tanto nada de esto está probado.*

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, me funciona bien el código es justamente lo que quería. Me falta la parte de la validación para cuando se pone un identificador que no existe para que en vez de que salte el error salte un "identificador no existe prueba de nuevo", de momento no consigo que funcione, lo seguiré intentando.

Comment: pone algo como `if(indiceCoche1  == -1 || indiceCoche2  == -1) { System.out.print("un id no existe"); return; }`

Comment: Gracias por responder, acabo de probar y no me funciona esta línea, al poner los identificadores correctamente imprime la línea "un id no existe" y se sale del programa

Comment: Te recomiendo que uses el  ciclo do-while para validar los datos de entrada.

Comment: Ok, Muchas gracias.